# Find intersection of A(x) and B(y) in complex plane plus corr. x and y

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

suppose I have the following Problem:

I have a complex function `A(x)` and a complex function `B(y)`. I know these functions cross in the complex plane. I would like to find out the corresponding `x` and `y` of this intersection point, numerically ( and/or graphically). What is the most clever way of doing that?

This is my starting point:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, pi

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10000)
y = np.linspace(1, 60, 10000)

def A_(x):
    return -1/( 8/(pi*x)*sqrt(1-(1/x)**2) - 1j*(8/(pi*x**2)) )
A = np.vectorize(A_)

def B_(y):
    return 3/(1j*y*(1+1j*y))
B = np.vectorize(B_)


real_A = np.real(A(x))
imag_A = np.imag(A(x))

real_B = np.real(B(y))
imag_B = np.imag(B(y))

plt.plot(real_A, imag_A, color='blue')
plt.plot(real_B, imag_B, color='red')
plt.show()
```

I don't have to plot it necessarily. I just need `x_intersection` and `y_intersection` (with some error that depends on `x` and `y`).

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**
I should have used different variable names. To clarify what i need:
`x` and `y` are numpy arrays and i need the index of the intersection point of each array plus the corresponding `x` and `y` value (which again is **not** the intersection point itself, but some value of the arrays `x` and `y` ).

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a [root-finding algorithm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/optimize.html#root-finding).

Comment: Move to the site  Mathematics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I find the minimum of the distance between the two curves.  Also, I cleaned up your code a bit (*eg*, `vectorize` wasn't doing anything useful).

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, pi
from scipy import optimize

def A(x):
    return -1/( 8/(pi*x)*sqrt(1-(1/x)**2) - 1j*(8/(pi*x**2)) )

def B(y):
    return 3/(1j*y*(1+1j*y))

#  The next three lines find the intersection
def dist(x):
    return abs(A(x[0])-B(x[1]))    
sln = optimize.minimize(dist, [1, 1])

#  plotting everything....
a0, b0 = A(sln.x[0]), B(sln.x[1])
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10000)
y = np.linspace(1, 60, 10000)    
a, b = A(x), B(y)

plt.plot(a.real, a.imag, color='blue')
plt.plot(b.real, b.imag, color='red')
plt.plot(a0.real, a0.imag, "ob")
plt.plot(b0.real, b0.imag, "xr")
plt.show()
```

The specific x and y values at the intersection point are `sln.x[0]` and `sln.x[1]`, since `A(sln.x[0])=B(sln.x[1])`.  If you need the index, as you also mention in your edit, I'd use, for example, `numpy.searchsorted(x, sln.x[0])`, to find where the values from the fit would insert into your `x` and `y` arrays.

---

I think what's a bit tricky with this problem is that the space for graphing where the intersection is (ie, the complex plane) does not show the input space, but one has to optimize over the input space.  It's useful for visualizing the solution, then, to plot the distance between the curves over the input space.  That can be done like this:

```
data = dist((X, Y))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.afmhot, interpolation='none', 
    extent=[min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)], origin="lower")
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
plt.plot(sln.x[0], sln.x[1], "xw")
plt.title("abs(A(x)-B(y))")
```

[image]

From this it seems much more clear how `optimize.minimum` is working -- it just rolls down the slope to find the minimum distance, which is zero in this case.  But still, there's no obvious single visualization that one can use to see the whole problem.

---

For other intersections one has to dig a bit more.  That is, @emma asked about other roots in the comments, and there I mentioned that there's no generally reliable way to find all roots to arbitrary equations, but here's how I'd go about looking for other roots.  Here I won't lay out the complete program, but just list the changes and plots as I go along.

First, it's obvious that for the domain shown in my first plot that there's only one intersection, and that there are no intersection in the region to the left.  The only place there could be another intersection is to the right, but for that I'll need to allow the `sqrt` in the def of `B` to get a negative argument without throwing an exception.  An easy way to do this is to add `0j` to the argument of the `sqrt`, like this, `sqrt(1+0j-(1/x)**2)`.  Then the plot with the intersection becomes

[image]

I plotted this over a broader range (`x=np.linspace(-10, 10, 10000)` and `y=np.linspace(-400, 400, 10000)`) and the above is the zoom of the only place where anything interesting is going on.  This shows the intersection found above, plus the point where it looks like the two curves might touch (where the red curve, `B`, comes to a point nearly meeting the blue curve `A` going upward), so that's the new interesting thing, and the thing I'll look for.

A bit of playing around with limits, etc, show that `B` is coming to a point asymptotically, and the equation of `B` is obvious that it will go to `0 + 0j` for large `+/- y`, so that's about all there is to say for `B`.

It's difficult to understand `A` from the above plot, so I'll look at the real and imaginary parts independently:

[image]

So it's not a crazy looking function, and the jumping between Re=const and Im=const is just the nature of sqrt(1-x<sup>-2</sup>), which is pure complex for `abs(x)<1` and pure real for `abs(x)>1`.

It's pretty clear now that the other time the curves are equal is at `y= +/-inf` and `x=0`.  And, quick look at the equations show that `A(0)=0+0j` and `B(+/- inf)=0+0j`, so this is another intersection point (though since it occurs at `B(+/- inf)`, it's sort-of ambiguous on whether or not it would be called an intersection).

So that's about it.  One other point to mention is that if these didn't have such an easy analytic solution, like it wasn't clear what `B` was at `inf`, etc, one could also graph/minimize, etc, by looking at `B(1/y)`, and then go from there, using the same tools as above to deal with the infinity. So using:

```
def dist2(x):
    return abs(A(x[0])-B(1./x[1]))
```

[image]

Where the min on the right is the one initially found, and the zero, now at `x=-0` and `1./y=0` is the other one (which, again, isn't interesting enough to apply an optimizer here, but it could be interesting in other equations).

---

Of course, it's also possible to estimate this by just finding the minimum of the data that goes into the above graph, like this:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = dist((X, Y))
r = np.unravel_index(data.argmin(), data.shape)
print x[r[1]], y[r[0]]
#  2.06306306306 1.8008008008    # min approach gave 2.05973231  1.80069353
```

But this is only approximate (to the resolution of `data`) and involved many more calculations (1M compared to a few hundred).  I only post this because I think it might be what the OP originally had in mind.

Comment: it took me a while to realize what you are doing here, but that solves my problem! thank you very much!

Comment: The solution is sort of deceptive in its simplicity, and possibly a bit difficult to understand.  I think this is due to the different spaces at play: (x,y) *vs* (A, B) *vs* (Re,Im).  Let me know if more explanation would help, especially if there's a particular point that's not clear.

Comment: Oh wow! I'm so impressed by your effort! Yes, it is a 4 dimensional problem (2d for the input domain, 2d for the complex output domain). that's what makes it difficult to visualize. But your colored graph is an awesome idea!! I really appreciate your work! Thank you very, very much!

Comment: i have one more question: what if there is more than one solution? optimize.minimize seems to stop after finding the first solution.

Comment: **Short:** to find different minima, set different initial guesses (eg, change the `[1,1]` in my call to `minimize`). **Longer:** Finding all solutions automatically is much more difficult. This is basically true for all optimizations: local optimizations are easy, global optimizations are hard. By analogy: it's easy to make a ball that will roll down a hill, but harder to make a ball that will automatically test all hills. Most optimizations use a gradient descent approach, and just "roll down the hill". There are different approaches to the global problem, but that's a big can of worms.

Comment: i see. well i feel like as soon as i have more time i will have to read more about this topic

Comment: @emma: sure, I'd never discourage further study, but please note I'm only saying there's no good *automatic* method to find all roots to *arbitrary equations*.  As I tried to show in the edit to my answer, other roots are usually easy to find with a bit of exploration. There's just not a good automatic way to do it.  So my suggestion is understand how to find local roots (zeros, minima, or whatever), and realize that it's also reasonable to just leave the question at local roots.

Comment: Although this is marked as the answer, in my opinion it is not the most clever, or creative. It is a brute force method that gives little insight into the problem, and in particular how one should go about solving such problems. Just my opinion. I have posted my own response below.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, two analytic solutions are derived for the roots of the problem. The first solution removes the parametric representation of x and solves for the roots directly in the (u, v) plane, where for example A(x): u(x) + i v(y) gives v(u) = f(u). The second solution uses a polar representation, e.g. A(x) is given by r(x) exp(i theta(x)), and offers a better understanding of the behavior of the square root as x passes through unity towards zero. Possible solutions occurring at the singular points are explored. Finally, a bisection root finding algorithm is constructed as a Python iterator to invert certain solutions. Summarizing, the one real root can be found as a solution to either of the following equations:

[image: Two solutions]

and gives:

> x0 = -2.059732
>
> y0 = +1.800694
>
> A(x0) = B(y0) = (-0.707131, -i 0.392670)

As in most problems there are a number of ways to proceed. One can use a "black box" and hopefully find the root they are looking for. Sometimes an answer is all that is desired, and with a little understanding of the functions this may be an adequate way forward. Unfortunately, it is often true that such an approach will provide less insight about the problem then others.

For example, algorithms find it difficult locating roots in the global space. Local roots may be found with other roots lying close by and yet undiscovered.  Consequently, the question arises: "Are all the roots accounted for?" A more complete understanding of the functions, e.g. asymptotic behaviors, branch cuts, singular points, can provide the global perspective to better answer this, as well as other important questions.

So another possible solution would be building one's own "black box." A simple bisection routine might be a starting point. Robust if the root lies in the initial interval and fairly efficient. This encourages us to look at the global behavior of the functions. As the code is structured and debugged the various functions are explored, new insights are gained, and the algorithm has become a tool towards a more complete solution to the problem. Perhaps, with some patience, a closed-form solution can be found. A Python iterator is constructed and listed below implementing a bisection root finding algorithm.

Begin by putting the functions A(x) and B(x) in a more standard form:

> C(x) = u(x) + i v(x)

and here the complex number i is brought out of the denominator and into the numerator, casting the problem into the form of functions of a complex variable. The new representation simplifies the original functions considerably. The real and imaginary parts are now clearly separated. An interesting graph is to plot A(x) and B(x) in the 3-dimensional space (u, v, x) and then visualize the projection into the u-v plane.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import real, imag
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') 
s = np.linspace(a, b, 1000)
ax.plot(f(s).real, f(s).imag, z, color='blue')
ax.plot(g(s).real, g(s).imag, z, color='red')
ax.plot(f(s).real, f(s).imag, 0, color='black')
ax.plot(g(s).real, g(s).imag, 0, color='black')
```

The question arises: "Can the parametric representation be replaced so that a relationship such as,

> A(x): u(x) + i v(x) gives v(u) = f(u)

is obtained?" This will provide A(x) as a function v(u) = f(u) in the u-v plane. Then, if for

> B(x): u(x) + i v(x) gives v(u) = g(u)

a similar relationship can be found, the solutions can be set equal to one another,

> f(u) = g(u)

and the root(s) computed. In fact, it is convenient to look for a solution in the square of the above equation. The worst case is that an algorithm will have to be built to find the root, but at this point the behavior of our functions are better understood. For example, if f(u) and g(u) are polynomials of degree n then it is known that there are n roots. The best case is that a closed-form solution might be a reward for our determination.

Here is more detail to the solution. For A(x) the following is derived:

[image: A(x) rationalized and v(u)=f(u) determined]

and v(u) = f(u) is just v(u) = constant. Similarly for B(x) a slightly more complex form is required:

[image: B(x) rationalized and v(u) = g(u) determined]

Look at the function g(u) for B(x). It is imaginary if u > 0, but the root must be real since f(u) is real. This means that u must be less then 0, and there is both a  positive and negative real branch to the square root. The sign of f(u) then allows one to pick the negative branch as the solution for the root. So the fact that the solution must be real is determined by the sign of u, and the fact that the real root is negative specifies what branch of the square root to choose.

In the following plot both the real (u < 0) and complex (u > 0) solutions are shown.

[image: Plot of real and imaginary solution g(u)]

The camera looks toward the origin in the back corner, where the red and blue curves meet. The z-axis is the magnitude of f(u) and g(u). The x and y axes are the real/complex values of u respectively. The blue curves are the real solution with (3 - |u|). The red curves are the complex solution with (3 + |u|). The two sets meet at u = 0. The black curve is f(u) equal to (-pi/8).

There is a divergence in g(u) at |u| = 3 and this is associated with x = 0. It is far removed from the solution and will not be considered further.

To obtain the roots to f = g it is easier to square f(u) and equate the two functions. When the function g(u) is squared the branches of the square root are lost, much like squaring the solutions for x**2 = 4. In the end the appropriate root will be chosen by the sign of f(u) and so this is not an issue.

[image: Solution from depressed cubic]

So by looking at the dependence of A and B, with respect to the parametric variable x, a representation for these functions was obtained where v is a function of u and the roots found. A simpler representation can be obtained if the term involving c in the square root is ignored.

The answer gives all the roots to be found. A cubic equation has at most three roots and one is guaranteed to be real. The other two may be imaginary or real. In this case the real root has been found and the other two roots are complex. Interestingly, as c changes these two complex roots may move into the real plane.

[image: Cubic with three real roots]

In the above figure the x-axis is u and the y axis is the evaluated cubic equation with constant c. The blue curve has c as (pi/8) squared. The red curve uses a larger and negative value for c, and has been translated upwards for purposes of demonstration. For the blue curve there is an inflection point near (0, 0.5), while the red curve has a maximum at (-0.9, 2.5) and a minimum at (0.9, -0.3).

The intersection of the cubic with the black line represents the roots given by: u**3 + c u + 3c = 0. For the blue curve there is one intersection and one real root with two roots in the complex plane. For the red curve there are three intersections, and hence 3 roots. As we change the value of the constant c (blue to red) the one real root undergoes a "pitchfork" bifurcation, and the two roots in the complex plane move into the real space.

Although the root (u_t, v_t) has been located, obtaining the value for x requires that (u, v) be inverted. In the present example this is a trivial matter, but if not, a bisection routine can be used to avoid the algebraic difficulties.

The parametric representation also leads to a solution for the real root, and it rounds out the analysis with an independent verification of the first result. Second, it answers the question about what happens at the singularity in the square root. Third, it gives a greater understanding of the multiplicity of roots.

The steps are: (1) convert A(x) and B(x) into polar form, (2) equate the modulus and argument giving two equations in two unknowns, (3) make a substitution for z = x**2. Converting A(x) to polar form:

[image: A(x) in polar form]

Absolute value bars are not indicated, and it should be understood that the moduli r(x) and s(x) are positive definite as their names imply. For B(x):

[image: B(x) in polar form]

The two equations in two unknowns:

[image: Two equations in two unknowns]

Finally, the cubic solution is sketched out here where the substitution z = x**2 has been made:

[image: Solution from polar form]

The solution for z = x**2 gives x directly, which allows one to substitute into both A(x) and B(x). This is an exact solution if all terms are maintained in the cubic solution, and there is no error in x0, y0, A(x0), or B(x0). A simpler representation can be found by considering terms proportional to 1/d as small.

Before leaving the polar representation consider the two singular points where: (1) abs(x) = 1, and (2) x = 0. A complicating factor is that the arguments behave something like 1/x instead of x. It is worthwhile to look at a plot of the arctan(a) and then ask yourself how that changes if its argument is replaced by 1/a. The following graphs will then look less foreign.

Consider the polar representation of B(x). As x approaches 0 the modulus and  argument tend toward infinity, i.e. the point is infinitely far from the origin and lies along the y-axis. Approaching 0 from the negative direction the point lies along the negative y-axis with varphi = (-pi/2), while approaching from the other direction the point lies along the positive y-axis with varphi = (+pi/2).

A somewhat more complicated behavior is exhibited by A(x). A(x) is even in x since the modulus is positive definite and the argument involves only x**2. There is a symmetry across the y-axis that allows us to only consider the x > 0 plane.

At x = 1 the modulus is just (pi/8), and as x continues to approach 0 so does r(x). The behavior of the argument is more complex. As x approaches unity from large positive values the argument is diverging towards +inf and so theta is approaching (+pi/2). As x passes through 1 the argument becomes complex. At x equals 0 the argument has reached its minimum value of -i. For complex arguments the arctan is given by:

[image: Arctan of complex number]

The following are plots of the arguments for A(x) and B(x). The x-axis is the value of x, and the y-axis is the value of the angle in units of pi. In the first plot theta is shown in blue curves, and as x approaches 1 the angle approaches (+pi/2). Theta is real because abs(x) >= 1, and notice it is symmetric across the y-axis. The black curve is varphi and as x approaches 0 it approaches plus or minus (pi/2). Notice it is an odd function in x.

[image: Real arguments]

In the second plot A(x) is shown where abs(x) < 1 and the argument becomes complex. Near x = 1 theta is equal to (+pi/2), the blue curve, minus a small imaginary part, the red curve. As x approaches zero theta is equal to (+pi/2) minus a large imaginary part. At x equals 0 the argument is equal to -i and theta = (+pi/2) minus an infinite imaginary part, i.e ln(0) = -inf:

[image: A(x) for abs(x) < 1]

The values for x0 and y0 are determined by the set of equations that equate modulus and argument of A(x) and B(x), and there are no other roots. If x0 = 0 was a root, then it would fall out of these equations. The same holds for x0 = 1. In fact, if one uses approximations in the argument of A(x) about these points, and then substitutes into the equation for the modulus, the equality cannot be maintained there.

Here is another perspective: consider the set of equations where x is assumed large and call it x_inf. The equation for the argument then gives x_inf = y_inf, where 1 is neglected with respect to x_inf squared. Upon substitution into the second equation a cubic is obtained in x_inf. Will this give the correct answer? Yes, if x0 is actually large, and in this case you might get away with it since x0 is approximately 2. The difference between the sqrt(4) and the sqrt(5) is around 10%. But does this mean that x_inf = 100 is a solution? No it does not: x_inf is only a solution if it equals x0.

The initial reason for examining the problem in the first place was to find a context for building a root-finding bisection routine as a Python iterator. This can be used to find any of the roots discussed here, and looks something like this:

```
class Bisection:

def __init__(self, a, b, func, max_iter):
    self.max_iter = max_iter
    self.count_iter = 0
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.func = func
    fa = func(self.a)
    fb = func(self.b)
    if fa*fb >= 0.0:
        raise ValueError

def __iter__(self):
    self.x1 = self.a
    self.x2 = self.b
    self.xmid = self.x1 + ((self.x2 - self.x1)/2.0)
    return self

def __next__(self):

    f1 = self.func(self.x1)
    f2 = self.func(self.x2)
    error = abs(f1 - f2)

    fmid = self.func(self.xmid)

    if fmid == 0.0:
        return self.xmid

    if f1*fmid < 0:
        self.x2 = self.xmid
    else:
        self.x1 = self.xmid

    self.xmid = self.x1 + ((self.x2 - self.x1)/2.0)
    f1 = self.func(self.x1)
    fmid = self.func(self.xmid)

    self.count_iter += 1
    if self.count_iter >= self.max_iter:
        raise StopIteration

    return self.xmid
```

The routine does only a minimal amount in the way of catching exceptions and was used to find x for the given solution in the u-v plane. The arguments a and b give the lower and upper brackets for the root to be found. The argument func is the function for the root to be found. This might look like: u0 - B(x).real. The constant max_iterations tells the iterator to stop after a given number of bisections has been attempted.

Comment: wow. i'm impressed by your effort. unfortunately i don't have time to go through all of that in the moment, but this looks like a very detailed analysis of the problem and i really appreciate your work. i hope i will have time soon to study your answer. thanks a lot for that!